# Reserve Number in Oracle Sequence Generator

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sequence

We have requirement to skip few defined number while generating the new number using Oracle Sequence Generator.

For Eg:- We have range defined from 0001-9999 but in this range, there are numbers 0011, 0020, 2056, 6547 never to be generated by Oracle sequencer.

Is it possible to do?

Comment: nothing inherent in a sequence definition to do that.  Why do you need to skip these?  Why not just start your sequence at 1 more than the highest number you want to skip?  Limiting sequences to a range of only 9999 smack of a flawed design or flawed understanding of how to best use sequences.  What do you do when your seq. reaches 9999?  How are you using these numbers?

Comment: I can see why someone would want to reserve some numbers, say, for the purposes of testing. I would make it simple by starting my sequence with 10000 and not worry about 4 only special numbers.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to do?

Sort of ... just start the sequence at 2057 and stop it at 6546 then you will never generate any of those values.

If you want to start at 1 and go up to 9999 skipping those values then, no, there is nothing in an Oracle sequence that allows you to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that purely within the built-in sequence mechanism. As a workaround you *could* have a wrapper function which skips the banned values, e.g.:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_seq RETURN NUMBER IS
  seq_val PLS_INTEGER := 11; -- any banned value
BEGIN
  WHILE seq_val IN (11, 20, 2056, 6547) LOOP
    seq_val := my_seq.nextval;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN seq_val;
END;
/
```

and then call `get_seq` in place of `my_seq.nextval`.

[db<>fiddle demp](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a167377caf2b369714cd76b463bc4a0c) with a smaller range, showing it skips values.

There are downsides of course; you may see a noticeable performance hit from the context switching, though with such a small range you presumably aren't going to be calling this very intensely. And if your banned numbers change you have to change the function, or have the function look them up from somewhere else - which you might need or want to anyway if you're avoiding existing PK values, say. Having to refer to different things to retrieve `nextval` (indirectly through the function) and `currval` (directly from the sequence) might be confusing. Etc. But it's an option...

If you are avoiding existing PK values then another option is to stick to a plain sequence and insert in a loop that exits when you *don't* get a constraint error - i.e. usually after one iteration. But it isn't clear what you are really trying to achieve.